# Clustering Multiple Attributes with ELKI

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, elki

I use the [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) framework to cluster a series of points, defined by their geographic coordinates (longitude, latitude). The algorithm I use is DBSCAN.

Now I would like to add another (numerical) attribute that weights the importance of the points (let's say size).

In theory, the points would now be defined in a 3 dimensional space (rather than 2D) and the distance would be a mixture of geographic distance and data distance.

In practice, I tried to do this in ELKI, but I step into a concrete problem.
The clustering algorithms expect a "database" as an input.

```
Clustering<DBSCANModel> de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.AbstractAlgorithm.run(Database database)
```

This database is created from a LisParametrization, which amongst other things, reads a database connection:

```
    params.addParameter(
        AbstractDatabase.Parameterizer.DATABASE_CONNECTION_ID, dbc);
```

Finally, this database connection reads the data from a 2D array:

*Import an existing data matrix (`double[rows][cols]`) into an ELKI database.*

```
    DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(array[][]);
```

My question is: is there any way of replacing this 2D array for a *D matrix?

For instance in my case, I would like to use a 3D array, to store the two geographic coordinates **and** the numerical attribute. Something like this:

array[][][]

Comment: You want a `double[rows][3]` array, not a `double[][][]`, obviously. Three column, not tensors. `double[][][]` would not be a matrix, but a *tensor*. It would be rows x columns x depth slices. This is common in convolutional deep learning, when you have 16x16 pixel patches, for 1000 locations of your input image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put weight on the instances, you should switch to GeneralizedDBSCAN, and implement a weighted [CorePredicate](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/elki/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/gdbscan/CorePredicate.java).

```
double[rows][cols]
```

is fine. You have three columns: longitude, latitute, weight.

[DimensionSelectingLatLngDistanceFunction](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/elki/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/distance/distancefunction/geo/DimensionSelectingLatLngDistanceFunction.java) can work with 3D vectors, too.
You just have to specify in which column latitude, and in which column longitude is stored.

Alternatively, you can build your own `DatabaseConnection`. It could return *two* relations: one is a 2d vector field containing latitude and longitude, the second is a 1d relation containing the weights only. But working with multiple relations can be tricky. Above approach is easier to use.